# Quais as vantagens de se usar diretivas e macros?

Tags: c, c++, preprocessador

Diretivas e macros influenciam na performance do programa?

Comment: Os compiladores otimizam as funções, não acho que é necessário a criação de macros, particularmente prefiro funções mesmo, acho mais fácil de dar manutenção. Já o uso de diretivas pode ser útil quando você precisa compilar o mesmo código para varias plataformas diferentes, um exemplo é a função `fflush` do que funciona no windows e a `__fpurge` exclusiva de sistemas linux. Pode especificar uma diretiva para elas para o compilador escolher a plataforma, elas servem para limpar o buffer, existe outros usos também.

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 10):

Elas em si não influenciam em nada na performance. O uso específico de alguma técnica com elas pode até trazer algum resultado.

No início só existia o pré-processador para realizar algumas coisas, mas hoje os compiladores possuem valores constantes de várias formas, funções *inline*, e muito do que era necessário não precisa mais ser usado.

Muitas vezes o recurso era usado para obter mais performance, mas os compiladores atuais permitem fazer o mesmo pela própria linguagem, que dá mais subsídio para fazer corretamente.

Hoje a recomendação é usar isto o mínimo possível. Esse é um recurso visto hoje mais como desvantagem. Ainda necessário por deficiências na linguagem propriamente dita.

É muito fácil cometer erros usando as diretivas. Tem uma série de regras que precisam ser seguidas para tudo dar certo. Mesmo que o programador domine todas - e são muitas - ainda não é fácil acertar sempre. O compilador não ajuda porque elas não fazem parte da linguagem. É só uma decisão de troca ou uso de texto sem entendimento do que está no código, sem escopo, sem contexto. É muito fácil imaginar que está fazendo uma coisa e estar realmente fazendo outra. O mecanismo é muito rudimentar.

Um exemplo óbvio de problema ocorre nas macros:

```
#define MAX(x,y) (x) > (y) ? (x) : (y)
```

Está bem feitinho, seguiu as regras recomendadas (não vou nem fazer o exemplo ingênuo que causa mais erro). Aí usa assim:

```
int x = MAX(y++, 1);
```

Que é transformado assim:

```
int x = (y++) > (1) ? (y++) : (1);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/MacroProblem.c).

Percebeu que não vai produzir o resultado que deseja? Tá cheio de armadilhas desse tipo, mesmo em situações mais inocentes. E tem muitas situações que são menos inocentes que estas.

Tem truques para evitar os problemas, mas quando precisa arrumar truques, em geral o mecanismo é errado.

Nem vou falar na dificuldade de *debugar* código assim.

Algumas diretivas servem para facilitar a construção e organização do código. Outras ajudam em construções complexas permitindo flexibilização e reuso de código.

No geral é isto. Algumas diretivas específicas podem ter suas vantagens mais específicas. Obviamente que `#include` e `#ifdef` ainda são mais úteis, mas elas não influenciam na performance diretamente. O que você faz com elas pode influenciar na performance já que pode decidir por uma alternativa melhor para uma determinada circunstância. Ele pode deixar de incluir um código necessário em determinado *build*, assim menos código ajuda manter o cache só com o que é necessário e também evita uma decisão em tempo de execução.

Há casos que é melhor usar mesmo.

Não dou uma resposta mais completa porque fica muito amplo. Cada diretiva tem sua peculiaridade. Cabem perguntas mais específicas.

Em C++ o uso é menos aconselhável ainda, até porque tem mais mecanismo que podem substituir isto.

Comment: "Hoje a recomendação é usar isto o mínimo possível." Por que?  - Veja, não estou questionando as conclusões (concordo com elas), mas acho que a resposta poderia ser melhorada se as devidas explicações (talvez até com alguns exemplos) também fossem dadas(os). :)

Comment: Valeu! Dai me avisa que eu volto pra deixar o meu +1. :)

Comment: Melhorou muitíssimo. Valeu! +1. E não acho que esteja um capítulo de livro não. A pergunta até podia ser inocente, mas gerou conteúdo importante (imho).

Comment: Há! Hoje eu me deparei com um problema do uso de macros ao portar um código de Linux pra Windows (e precisar incluir o famigerado `windows.h`): http://stackoverflow.com/q/5004858/2896619. Naturalmente lembrei dessa postagem. :)