# Quando usar const e quando usar #define?

Tags: c, enums, constantes, diretivas-de-compilação

Já que as duas fazem a mesma função existe alguma diferença entre uma e outra?

Vou tirar o código deste site como exemplo [C - Constants & Literals](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm)

## The `#define` preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LENGTH 10   
#define WIDTH  5
#define NEWLINE '\n'

int main() {

   int area;  
  
   area = LENGTH * WIDTH;
   printf("value of area : %d", area);
   printf("%c", NEWLINE);

   return 0;
}
```

Quando o código é compilado e executado reproduz o seguinte resultado:

> value of area : 50

## The `const` keyword

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   const int  LENGTH = 10;
   const int  WIDTH = 5;
   const char NEWLINE = '\n';
   int area;  
   
   area = LENGTH * WIDTH;
   printf("value of area : %d", area);
   printf("%c", NEWLINE);

   return 0;
}
```

Quando o código e compilado e executado reproduz o seguinte resultado:

> value of area : 50

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Elas não fazem a mesma coisa. São semanticamente diferentes. Mesmo que seja frequente produzir o mesmo resultado, é uma eventualidade.

## `#define`

A primeira é um [diretiva de pré-processador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115311/101) de código. É apenas um texto sendo substituído por outro sem nenhum tipo de verificação. Pode dar todo tipo de bobagem. É um truque realizado antes da compilação que nem sempre traz os resultados esperados por um programador mais ingênuo ou descuidado. Ela vive desde sua inclusão até o fim do arquivo que estiver sendo compilado.

Em geral deve ser evitado sempre que possível. Mas há casos úteis.

Dá pra ser criativo com isto e tudo pode explodir na sua cara ;) É possível controlar o fluxo da compilação baseado nestas "constantes". Dá para trocar qualquer parte do código, não só valores.

Veja ["#define" define uma variável global?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/347134/101) e [Por que tem tantos parênteses em macro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192041/101) (usado em outro contexto, mas mostra como é complicado fazer certo).

## `const`

Este é uma [declaração de identificador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) presente no código com [escopo e tempo de vida no código.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) É verificado pelo compilador e tem um tipo. Pode ser usado em todas circunstâncias onde seria usado uma variável (de fato não é totalmente uma constante). Otimizações do compilador podem fazer o acesso ao valor de forma direta e evitar consumo de tempo e espaço. Obviamente isso só ocorre quando for viável.

Notará uma diferença quando estiver *debugando* o código.

## `enum`

Conheça também o [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum), ele é até mais próximo do `#define`, ainda que também tenham semânticas diferentes. Ele possui quase todas as vantagens dos dois sem as desvantagens principais. Ao contrário do que muitos acreditam, pode haver um só valor constante em uma enumeração que sempre será usado durante a compilação e nunca armazenado, igual ao `#define`, mas ele tem contexto e verificação do compilador.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: vlw @bigown agora eu vou ficar atento quando eu tiver que usar **const** e **#define** +1

Answer (score 4):

Há algumas situações em que não podes usar objectos (variáveis com `const`)

```
#define XPTO 42
const int xpto = 42;

switch (valor) {
    case XPTO: // OK
    case xpto: // erro
}

int arraynormal[XPTO]; // OK
int arraynormal[xpto]; // erro (excepto VLA)
```

Mais geralmente: os objectos ocupam espaço de memória; os #defines não

```
int *p = &xpto; // ok
int *p = &XPTO; // erro
```

Answer (score 2):

Scott Meyers, em seu livro:

> C++ Eficaz -55 maneiras de aprimorar seus programas e projetos diz:
>   **“prefira o compilador ao pré-processador”**

`#define` pode ser tratado como se não fizesse parte da linguagem
propriamente dita. Esse é um de seus problemas.

Quando você faz algo como:

`#define` **VALORX** 2.33

pode ser que o nome simbólico VALORX nunca seja visto pelos compiladores; ele pode ser removido pelo pré-processador antes que o código-fonte chegue a um compilador.

Como resultado, o nome **VALORX** talvez não entre na tabela de símbolos, o que pode ser confuso se você receber um erro durante a compilação envolvendo o uso da constante, pois a mensagem de erro talvez se referencie a 2.33, mas não a **VALORX**.

Se **VALORX** fosse definido em um arquivo de cabe-
çalho que você não escreveu, você não teria ideia de onde veio esse 2.33, e
perderia tempo tentando encontrá-lo.

A solução é substituir a macro por uma constante:

`const double Valor_X= 2.33`

Como uma constante de linguagem, **Valor_X** é definitivamente visto
pelos compiladores e, certamente, é inserido em suas tabelas de símbolos.
Além disso, no caso de uma constante de ponto flutuante (como nesse
exemplo), o uso da constante pode levar a um código menor do que com
um `#define`. Isso ocorre porque a substituição cega do pré-processador
do nome de macro **VALORX** por 2.33 pode resultar em cópias múltiplas
de 2.33 em seu código objeto, enquanto que o uso da constante
**Valor_X** nunca deve resultar em mais de uma cópia.