# Qual é o tamanho de um "enum" em C?

Tags: c, c++, enums

Em geral o `enum` guarda um inteiro, posso considerar que este é o tamanho dele?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quer saber o tamanho com segurança a melhor coisa a fazer é usar o `sizeof`, até porque o próprio `int` não tem tamanho máximo garantido, então pode variar.

Se quer ter uma ideia do tamanho ocupado, pode considerar que o normal é ser um `int`.

Alguns compiladores possuem extensões que permitem trabalhar com tamanhos diferentes (por exemplo com `__attribute__((packed))`), mas dentro da normalidade um dado que contém uma enumeração na verdade contém apenas um `int`, e é melhor não fugir deste padrão.

Tanto que é comum usar `enum` para criar constantes de valores inteiros. Essa forma tem [vantagens em relação ao `const` e ao `#define`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101).

Note que não há espaço ocupado pela definição da enumeração. Assim como `struct` ou `union`, esta é uma declaração de código para o compilador saber como gerar a fórmula correta para acesso ao dado na memória, mas ela desaparece depois de gerado o código de máquina, só o dado existirá na memória. Essas declarações servem para orientar o programador melhor. Em Assembly nem é possível criar esse tipo de coisa, o programador deve se virar para organizar e acessar a memória do jeito que precisa, esse conceito é abstrato.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).