# Qual o limite de vetores multidimensionais?

Tags: c, array, matriz, memória

Estou a fazer um teste e dá-me um erro quando tento criar um vetor[1000][1000]. Existe limites para vetores?

O código de erro (**aplicação deixa de responder**) é a seguinte:

```
int main (){

    int DIM_X = 1000;
    int DIM_Y = 1000;

    int vectorMD[DIM_X][DIM_Y];
    int x,y;

    for(x=0;x<DIM_X;x++){
        for(y=0;y<DIM_Y;y++){
            vectorMD[x][y] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que recebes?

Comment: O erro seria a aplicação deixar de responder?

Comment: Boas, Respondendo a perguntas que me colocaram acima: 1. O Erro não é de compilação, é na execução. 2. O erro que dá é quando executado: aparece uma mensagem do windows "A aplicação deixou de responder". Não tinha a ideia de haver limites mas como estou a rever um pouco o C mas numa máquina Windows, fiquei confuso. Sim, estou a usar o DevC+++ mas também testei no Code:Blocks. Também compilei e executei numa consola de PowerShell.
Todos falharam. Algo me está a escapar. Cumps

Comment: QUanto de memória você tem na máquina, e o que mais está rondando nela?

Comment: Boas, 
8GB e não estava  a executar nada mais.

Comment: @pintasart Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boas,

Depois de vários testes, com diferentes IDE/compiladores e SO, obtive o mesmo erro. 
Depois de alguma pesquisa, encontrei uma explicação que me pareceu válida e que após testar não deu erro.
Em resumo, eu estava a querer testar o desempenho em preencher um vetor 1000x10000, de diferentes formas mas definia e inicializava esse vector dentro de uma função, logo o escopo é local e a pilha tem limites mais restritivos.
Definindo o vector como variável global, já não dá erros. 
E assim,  creio ter percebido o problema.

Cumps

Answer (score 2):

O limite é a quantidade de memória virtual disponível, que normalmente é bem maior que a RAM do computador. Ou seja, não tem limite.

Na verdade este código não tem erros como pode ser visto abaixo. Eu só dei uma organizada maior nele. Não mudei a variável de tamanho da dimensão, mas normalmente se [usa `#define` ou `const` ou `enum`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101).

Se estiver em um IDE, principalmente um ruim, tipo Dev C++, o problema é no IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main () {
    int DIM_X = 1000;
    int DIM_Y = 1000;
    int vectorMD[DIM_X][DIM_Y];
    for (int x = 0; x < DIM_X; x++) for (int y = 0; y < DIM_Y; y++) vectorMD[x][y] = x;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/p9NSkr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fgdyuqxz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MultiDimentional.c).

Comment: O fato do retorno da função `main` ser `int` mas sem retornar explicitamente um valor não interfere?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss O compilador pode te dar uma warning em relação a isso, mas warning não é erro de compilação.

Comment: @jsbueno a memória ocupada será de 4MB.

Comment: ih...erro de escala dos grandes ... Hahahaha... acho que preciso dormir mais.