# Por que tem tantos parênteses em macro?

Tags: c, c++, estilo-de-codificação, macro

Vendo isto, intriga porque precisa desses parênteses que parecem desnecessários.  Qual a funcionalidade deles?

```
#define SUB(x, y) ((x) * (y))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Porque macro é só uma substituição de textos, não é uma construção da linguagem que considera a semântica do código, sem os parênteses o argumento pode se confundir com a expressão. Veja

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SUB_UNSAFE(x, y) x * y
#define SUB(x, y) ((x) * (y))

int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n", SUB_UNSAFE(4 - 4, 2));
    printf("%d\n", SUB(4 - 4, 2));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/TBUVEV). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/auzamfpl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Macro.c).

Dá pra ver que se os parênteses tem situação que o cálculo é feito errado porque a precedência na expressão se confunde com o argumento e mistura tudo porque na verdade fica assim:

```
4 - 4 * 2
```

Para visualizar melhor:

```
4 - (4 * 2) => 4 - 8 => -4
```

Mas o correto é:

```
(4 - 4) * (2) => 0 * 2 => 0
```