# Erros diferentes em código C em compiladores diferentes

Tags: c, sintaxe

No seguinte código abaixo existe um erro que o compilador LCCx86 para Windows afirma existir, porém copiei os códigos de uma aula de C que estou assistindo.

[Link da aula, para quem se interessar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBoWPFDQC_I&index=4&list=PLxI8Can9yAHf8k8LrUePyj0y3lLpigGcl)

No compilador C Online https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php
Ele exibe outros erros!

1. Qual o erro?
2. Porquê, compiladores diferentes, exibem erros diferentes?
3. A linguagem não é padronizada?
4. Ou eu que não estou entendendo os erros?

---

```
#define MAX 50;

typedef int TIPOCHAVE;

typedef struct {
    TIPOCHAVE chave;
} REGISTRO;

typedef struct {
    REGISTRO A[MAX]; //Linha 10
    int nroElem;
} LISTA;
```

alguns dos erros:

> ```
> PS D:\Cursos\C> lcc .\arranjos.c
> Error arranjos.c: 10  syntax error; found `;' expecting ']'
> Error arranjos.c: 10  syntax error; found `]' expecting '}'
> Error arranjos.c: 10  skipping `]'
> Error arranjos.c: 10  empty declaration
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pré-processamento

O problema é este ponto-e-vírgula:

```
#define MAX 50;
```

O motivo é que a `#define` funciona (falando de uma forma um tanto simplista) ao copiar e colar no resto do código as ocorrências da primeira palavra pelo restante. Elas são resolvidas em uma etapa chamada pré-processamento, que tem como finalidade resolver todas as `#define`s e `#include`s e também eliminar os comentários. O pré-processamento ocorre em cima do código-fonte ao fazer substituições de texto. A compilação de fato começa em cima do código-fonte já pré-processado. Inclusive, é possível você ver a saída do pré-processador ao invocar o seu compilador com as flags corretas. No caso do LCC é assim:

```
lcc -E arranjos.c
```

O GCC é da mesma forma:

```
gcc -E arranjos.c
```

Este comando vai fazer o pré-processamento do arquivo `arranjos.c`.

No caso do seu programa, o pré-processador vai substituir `MAX` por `50;`, produzindo isso:

```
typedef int TIPOCHAVE;

typedef struct {
    TIPOCHAVE chave;
} REGISTRO;

typedef struct {
    REGISTRO A[50;];
    int nroElem;
} LISTA;
```

E é esse código acima que o compilador de verdade vai enxergar. Observe a linha 10:

```
    REGISTRO A[50;];
```

Observe que esse ponto-e-vírgula dentro da dimensão do array faz o compilador engasgar.

Finalmente, compiladores diferentes vão dar erros diferentes porque a especificação da linguagem diz como o compilador deve interpretar código bem-formado e como transformá-lo em um executável. Entretanto, quando o que ocorre é código malformado, a especificação fala pouca coisa. Assim sendo, o que o compilador deve fazer frente a código malformado acaba ficando a cargo de quem desenvolveu o compilador, e desta forma, compiladores diferentes darão erros diferentes.

## Erros

1. No caso, o primeiro erro que você tem é bem claro:

   `` syntax error; found `;' expecting ']' ``

   Este erro diz que o compilador achou um ponto-e-vírgula que não deveria estar lá e esperava um fecha-colchetes.

   Os erros subsequentes ocorrem porque o compilador acabou ficando confuso com o primeiro erro, mas suponho que a estratégia de recuperação de erros dele tenha sido fingir que o que ele queria encontrar, mas não encontrou, estaria de fato lá. Assim sendo, ao encontrar o `;` quando ele esperava um `]`, ele fingiu que isso:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       REGISTRO A[50;];
       int nroElem;
   } LISTA;
   ```

   era na verdade isso:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       REGISTRO A[50];];
       int nroElem;
   } LISTA;
   ```

   Ou seja ele fingiu/chutou/adivinhou que você tinha esquecido de colocar o `]`.
2. Mas daí, ele encontra um outro `]` a mais. Neste ponto, ele esperava ou a definição de um outro campo do `struct` ou o `}` do fim da `struct`. A segunda opção é a mais simples, então ele lançou como erro isso:

   `` Error arranjos.c: 10  syntax error; found `]' expecting '}' ``

   E então para recuperar, ele fingiu que o `}` estava lá:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       REGISTRO A[50];}];
       int nroElem;
   } LISTA;
   ```
3. Nesta etapa, o compilador encontra novamente o `]` lá de bobeira, sem estar fechando nada. A solução é pular ele emitindo o erro `` Error arranjos.c: 10  skipping `]' `` e fingir que o código estava assim:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       REGISTRO A[50];};
       int nroElem;
   } LISTA;
   ```
4. Com essas modificações, ele acaba enxergando o `typedef` desta forma:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       REGISTRO A[50];};
   ```

   E neste caso, faltou o nome que vem antes deste último `;`. Logo, ele dá mais um erro:

   `Error arranjos.c: 10  empty declaration`
5. Depois disso, o compilador deve produzir outros erros. Em especial, ele vai pensar que `nroElem` está fora do `struct` e vai ver o `}` depois sobrando de bobeira.

Na verdade, você só tinha um erro, que era o `;` dentro da `#define`. Entretanto, devido a estratégia de recuperação de erros inadequada do compilador, ele acabou vendo um monte de erros diferentes onde tinha apenas um porque ele ficou confuso. Cada compilador tem uma estratégia de erros diferente dos demais (friso novamente, que a especificação da linguagem C foca em código bem formado e fala pouco sobre como lidar com código malformado).

Por outro lado, não dá para culpar o compilador porque não existe estratégia ótima de recuperação de erros. Quando o código é malformado, o compilador perde as garantias estruturais que a linguagem o daria e ele passa a ter que tentar adivinhar o que o programador queria, e em muitos casos este processo de adivinhação pode levar a resultados bem ruins. Por exemplo, tente compilar um código em Python, Java ou qualquer outra linguagem com o compilador de C para ver que qualquer compilador vai ficar bastante confuso e que sempre que ele tentar fazer um esforço para entender algo, vai acabar ficando ainda mais confuso.

Por fim, o GCC deve usar uma estratégia de recuperação de erros melhor neste caso (em outros casos pode ser diferente). Eis a saída do GCC com este código:

```
arranjos.c:1:15: error: expected ‘]’ before ‘;’ token
 #define MAX 50;
           ^
arranjos.c:10:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAX’
 REGISTRO A[MAX]; //Linha 10
            ^~~
```

Em especial, o GCC é inteligente (ao menos neste caso) para saber que o erro ocorreu dentro de uma macro (ou seja, uma `#define`) e dar mensagens de erro mais precisas que o LCC sem se confundir.

Answer (score 5):

> Qual o erro?

Tem um `;` no `#define`, e não deve ter, isso é sintaxe errada. Se a aula ensinou assim, fuja dela. Em qualquer compilador isso não faz o que deseja.

> Porquê compiladores diferentes exibem erros diferentes?

Porque eles são diferentes. Eles podem lidar como eles quiserem com o código desde que obedeçam a especificação.

> A linguagem não é padronizada?

Sim, e desde que o compilador respeite o que foi especificado ele pode funcionar como quiser. Se a especificação dissesse cada detalhe a ser seguido não precisaria ter mais que um compilador. Cada um faz como acha melhor e cada programador escolher o compilador que melhor lhe atende.

O compilador pode até mesmo adicionar coisas novas.

Tem compiladores que nem atendem a especificação. Eles dizem que compilam C, mas não dizem que atendem o padrão. Ninguém é obrigado atender o padrão, só não pode dizer que atende sem atender. Mesmo assim não sei se aconteceria alguma coisa se mentir.

> Ou eu que não estou entendendo os erros?

Isso só você pode responder.

## O erro

Veja [O que é comportamento indefinido, não especificado e definido pela implementação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173886/101).

Mas nem é o caso. O compilador pode tratar os erros como quiser, pode verificar na ordem que quiser, pode parar no momento que quiser.

Como não temos os erros nos dois compiladores não podemos comparar os comportamentos.

É fato que um erro pode desencadear outros e resolvendo este, resolve todos, tanto que só existe um e mostrou 4, possivelmente mostraria outros se o código fosse maior ou se o compilador não parasse quando já enroscou muito.

E o erro em um local gerou erro em outro. Primeiro entenda [como o `#define` funciona e as alternativas a ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/101), o que eu teria usado neste caso. Eu o considero **quase** obsoleto.

Então quando o código é compilado, há um processamento do texto trocando todos os textos `MAX` por `50;` que é o texto que está escrito no seu código. Vamos ver a primeira ocorrência dele:

```
REGISTRO A[MAX];
```

Depois de processado ficaria

```
REGISTRO A[50;];
```

Esse `;` dentro da declaração do *array* é proibida em qualquer compilador.

Existem compiladores que "percebem" o tipo de erro e podem dar uma mensagem melhor, isto é prerrogativa dele fazer, a linguagem não diz como o erro deve ser tratado, qual deve ser a mensagem, nada disso. Então algum compilador pode dar uma mensagem indicando o erro no lugar certo, ou seja na linha 1, já que o compilador pode entender que este é um erro comum. Mas a maioria preferirá dar o erro onde ele ocorreu de fato.

Compiladores mais inteligentes são mais difíceis de desenvolver, e muitas vezes demorar mais para compilar até achar o verdadeiro erro. Em geral só os compiladores que tem muito esforço é inteligente, por isso só recomendo usar compiladores "exóticos" se for realmente necessário.

E aí um erro desencadeia os outros já que o compilador entende que depois do 50 está encerrando a linha. Então a sintaxe daquela linha fica errada porque não foi fechada, e a próxima linha de código está errada porque nenhum linha nova começa com um `]`, e ele se perde achando que viria o fechamento da estrutura e ainda acaba sobrando um `;` solta que está encerrando nada, já que houve um encerramento anterior onde não devia.

Por disso que digo e repito: a pessoa não sabe programar até que ela entenda todos os caracteres que está no seu código, até o espaço em branco. Tudo tem influência no código, seja pro compilador, seja para a legibilidade.

Este código compila:

```
#define MAX 50

typedef int TIPOCHAVE;

typedef struct {
    TIPOCHAVE chave;
} REGISTRO;

typedef struct {
    REGISTRO A[MAX]; //Linha 10
    int nroElem;
} LISTA;

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/cjYy75). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/fzzfzdgo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Define.c).

Comment: Não é que seja "proibido" pôr o `;` no final do `#define`; é que, se o `;` estiver na definição, esse `;` vai ser substituído nas ocorrências do _token_ definido. Isso é raramente o que se quer; mas pode ser que o programador tenha levado isso em consideração. De todo modo, o preprocessador não proíbe o uso de `;` no final de `#define`, e obedientemente substitui o _token_ com o `;`.

Comment: @Wtrmute isso, não fui feliz nas palavras, vou editar

Comment: esse include do stdio.h era desnecessária? visto que não temos um print?

Comment: @Dorathoto de fato ficou no gabarito do ideone, não precisava mesmo. Melhorei a resposta.