# Free() em struct com char array

Tags: c, struct

Eu tenho o *struct*

```
struct data {
    int code;
    char name[50];
    char feature[30];
};
typedef struct data Data;
```

e a função:

```
void free_data(Data *data) {
    if (data != NULL)
        free(data);
}
```

Mas o *free()* não está tornando o pontei nulo, ou seja, ao fazer

```
data == NULL; // returns false
```

Já tentei de várias outras formas, mas não obtive sucesso.

Desde já, obrigado.

Comment: Como você diz que `free` não está funcionando?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, meu objetivo é que o free torne o ponteiro nulo. Irei editar na pergunta, pois acho que não me expressei bem.

Comment: Mas o `free` não faz isso. Sem falar que como você passa o ponteiro como valor (não como referência), tudo que você faça na variável `data` não afetará o parâmetro.

Comment: Onde usou o `malloc()`? Por que quer que ele seja nulo?

Comment: Reforçando o que o @JeffersonQuesado disse, `free` não torna o ponteiro nulo, apenas libera o espaço associado, algo que pode confirmar na [documentação do free](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/). Como ultima nota, nem o espaço liberado é colocado a `NULL` ou `0`, apenas é marcado como livre internamente

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar uma `macro` se tiver cuidado. O uso de macros [é passível de críticas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115316/64969), sem falar que usar de modo descuidado irá produzir resultados errados.

> Olhe [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004858/4438007) para entender como macros mal definidas podem atrapalhar a vida do programador

O que você deseja é ter o seguinte texto:

```
if (ptr != NULL) {
  free(ptr);
  ptr = NULL;
}
```

Para por em uma macro você poderia defini-la assim:

```
#define libera_anula(ptr) do { if ((ptr) != NULL) {\
    free(ptr);\
    (ptr) = NULL;\
  }\
} while(0)
```

Note que o `do..while` foi posto de tal forma que você é obrigado a por o `;` para chamar essa macro, fazendo-a parecer com uma função da linguagem que tem como efeito colateral anular o valor da variável passada como parâmetro. Veja mais: [Por que usar do while(0)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80669/64969)

Também vale perceber que as chamadas de `ptr` eu coloquei entre parênteses para tentar mitigar alguns problemas de aritmética de ponteiros.

E como dito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248255/64969) e no [comentário do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248249/free-em-struct-com-char-array#comment508903_248249), você só deve usar `free` em uma região da memória que fora alocada dinamicamente.

Mais sobre macros:

- [Onde criar macros em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75075/64969)
- [Macro vs Function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9104568/4438007)

### Arenques vermelhos

Um [arenque vermelho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring?wprov=sfti1) é uma estratégia para desviar o foco de atenção do que realmente está acontecendo para algo de mínima significância. Como o Aringarosa ("arenque rosa" em italiano, um descuido do autor que confundiu com o "rosa" espanhol) em "O Código Da Vinci" do Dan Brown. A sua pergunta está cheio de arenques.

O primeiro é no próprio título: "Free() em struct com char array". Aqui o vetor de caracteres não influiu em nada, nem irá influir ocasionalmente na sua estrutura; poderia incluir caso fosse alocação dinâmica do vetor, mas não é o caso, ele já é alocado junto à estrutura, ele pertence à estrutura.

Outro arenque vermelho é que o `free` em nenhum momento foi indicado que não funcionava, apenas que ele "não se comportava da maneira que você queria para a sua aplicação". Para começar, por mais que o `free` fosse sobrecarregado em uma macro para fazer conforme está acima na minha resposta, o simples fato de você passar um ponteiro para ele ser liberado implica que você não está mexendo no dado original, então mesmo a macro não resolveria seu problema. Quando você passa um ponteiro como argumento, esse ponteiro é copiado (passagem por valor) para ser usado internamente na função. Alterar o valor do ponteiro só tem efeito dentro da função, não fora. Você pode fazer `data = NULL;` dentro da função `free_data` que isso não terá efeito colateral algum externo à função.

Enfim, um arenque vermelho do qual você foi vítima foi que em algum momento você relacionou a espaço não alocado com `NULL`, mas não é esse o caso. O [@Isac](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/82711/isac) percebeu muito bem isso [em seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/248249/free-em-struct-com-char-array#comment508919_248249), até pondo a documentação oficial da função para você ficar mais embasado.

Answer (score 2):

Você deve utilizar o free apenas em uma estrutura alocada dinânicamente (com malloc/calloc). Ou seja, a sintaxe correta seria:

```
typedef struct data {
  int code;
  char name[50];
  char feature[30];
}Data;

void free_data(Data *data) {
  if (data != NULL)
    free(data);
}

int main(){
  Data *data = malloc(sizeof(Data));
  ...
  Outras instruções utilizando 'data'
  ...
  free_data(data);
  return 0;
}
```