# Erro de Sintaxe/Possivelmente Logica em uma Funcao Recursiva

Tags: c

Enunciado da questão:
Considere as funções a seguir:

```
int suc(int n) { return n+1; }
int pred(int n) { return n-1; }
```

Usando essas funções (e nenhum operador aritmético), crie funções recursivas para determinar:
(a) A soma de dois números naturais.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define pred(n) { return n-1; } 
#define suc(n) { return n+1; } 

int soma (int x, int y ){
if ( x == 0) return y;
if ( y == 0) return x;
return soma((suc(x)),(pred(y)));
}

int main(void){
int x = 4;
int y = 3;
int result = soma(x,y);
}
```

Alguem sabe me falar qual o erro de sintaxe/logica nessa solucao?
Obrigado desde ja

Comment: Não seria apenas `#define pred(n) n-1`? Se me lembro bem, isso é uma macro, não uma função.

Comment: Muito obrigado! É isso mesmo, acabei de corrigir e deu certo!

Comment: Macros são questionáveis. [Nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/248263/64969) eu linko várias referências criticando o uso delas. Em suma, faça uso consciente dessa funcionalidade. Possivelmente você não precisa dela